# How to replace where clause on SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to replace column name on where clause. But the problem is be replace string has     quotation mark.

```
TBL407.[POSTINGDATE] >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND TBL407.[POSTINGDATE] <= '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
```

It should be replace with [POSTINGDATE] -> [Posting Date]

When I tried to replace like this;

```
 REPLACE('TBL407.[POSTINGDATE] >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND TBL407.[POSTINGDATE] <= '2023-01-31 23:59:59'','POSTINGDATE', 'Posting Date')
```

Of course it's not working. The quotation mark break this. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you are confused about what the REPLACE function does. You can't just use it arbitrarily change your where clause like this.

Comment: Actually, where clause comes from project. I need to change this. Unfortunately, we cannot intervene within the project. I wonder is that possible this?

Comment: replacing goes only with dynamic sql or a sql proxy who will analyse the query string and replace it.

Comment: I just wondered is that possible. Thanks!

Comment: The duplicate link answers your immediate question: double up `'` to escape them `''`. But that wont help you unless you are using dynamic SQL, and I honestly hope you are not as it's pretty advanced and complex, and not usually necessary.